Why does shirt keeps moving in simulation? It should be stable
I wanted the shirt I downloaded as an obj. file to be hanging but this keeps happening to me no matter what I do. Why?
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LbaEZ9nB0A


Hi Josef, can you illustrate and/or describe what's wrong? We don't want questions (or answers) to rely on outside information. You can also upload your .blend file.

how do I upload blend file?

it keeps moving like crazy around vertices i set for the shape. it is never actually hanging

You can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

The problem is probably that your object has thickness, so the faces are colliding right away. Maybe first apply the scale, and also lower down the self collisions distance. Also the topology is pretty bad so I don't think it helps the cloth simulation.
